# Various Makefile Issues

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile

I am trying to compile my project for use of debugging with gprof; however, I am having numerous issues.

Right now, I am trying to create a separate target in my makefile that is 'gprof' which depends upon the executable. This target, beforehand, adds the flags -g -gdwarf-3 and -pg to the compilation flags and -pg to the linker flags.

The unfortunate thing is I cannot get gprof to run successfully, as my compiled binary doesn't produce the required gmon.out. There are also side issues regarding this process.

1.) I am getting an issue regarding a clang warning when trying to introduce gdwarf-3 flags. This issue is `clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-gdwarf-3'`.

2.) The makefiles (3 of them, one main, one more main executable, and one for linked library) were produced by premake. I have edited them to introduce compiler and linker flags.

3.) I don't know how to compile the linked library (vecmath) under gprof (do I even need to?). The ar command doesn't accept the necessary -pg flag needed for gprof.

I am trying to perform this on a macbook air 2011, MAC OSX 10.8. I will try to attempt this later in linux.

My three makefiles are shared [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fectp30kq7ukz37/mcPIwDB9wP). Makefile calls a5.make and vecmath_makefile (this file title was edited). Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: My first comment would be to tag this with clang rather than gcc, as it seems as though you are using clang. (I can't look at the dropbox files due to where I am at the moment) Second, it appears as though clang does not use -gdwarf3 as an option.

You may want to look into gcc for the Mac as well if you would like to use dwarf3.

Comment: Seemed to be a CLANG issue, my makefiles work fine on linux.